# JQuery UI Dialog Buttons How to Access Selected Value of List

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

So I am pretty much have a list of buttons. I want to access variables or the select the button because I need to return information about the option selected.

Whenever I do this, all the console.log information in relation to `i`, `name`, or `list[name]` returns the last option in the dialog. The console.log that go with $(this) return just the dialog box. I find the selected button in the dialog.

Can someone suggest a way for me to return the selected value in the `click` method of the buttons. Please let me know if it is usually done another way.

```
    var i = 0, buttons = [];
    var list_names = _.keys(list);

    for(i = 0; i < _.size(list); i++) {
      var name = _.keys(list)[i];
      //var name = list_names[i];
      //TODO: new line characters and/or <br /> don't actually make new lines
      buttons[i] = {
        text: "Name = " + name + "\n" +
             "ID = " + list[name]._id + "\n" +
             "Rev = " + list[name]._rev,
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          //TODO: fix this always returns last item not the selected one
          console.log($(this));
          console.log(i);
          console.log(name);
          console.log(list[name]);
          return callbackAfterSelect(list[name]);
        }
      }
    };

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      dialogClass: "no-close",
      title: "Select Prescription",
      width: 'auto',
      buttons: buttons
    });
```

I will say that the buttons' Text do have different and correct `Name`, `ID`, and `Rev` displaying. I think it something about `var name` being dependent on `i` and after the buttons have been made and displayed `i` and therefore `name` will be the last value. I just don't know how to do this different, tried many things with the same result or an error.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the click event of the button like below with in above for loop. add the attributes to the button like Name, Index, List etc... And in the Log function, write the console.log.

```
                $('#' + list[name]._id).bind({
                    click: function () {
                        Log($(this).attr('Name'), $(this).attr('Index'), $(this).attr('ListName'), $('#' + list[name]._id));
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better where in the for loop I add this, as well as where I should add the attributes to the buttons?